# Fastest way of writing heavy content to csv/text file in matlab: currently using writetable

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a huge arrays in matlab that I am concatenating into a table and then I am dumping that table into a .csv file. Shown below:

```
% Create manipulated results with noise table
busResultNoise = array2table(busResult_arr); %This command converts the array into a table
% Horizontally concatenate timestamp table and bus data measurements with
% noise table
busResultNoise = horzcat(timeStamp_bus_tab,busResultNoise); %adds the timestamps array
% Assign same variable to busResultNoise as in busResult table
busResultNoise.Properties.VariableNames= busResult.Properties.VariableNames;%adds column names
%Export csv
writetable(busResultNoise,'BusDataWithNoise.csv');
```

This works great especially if the table/array is small. Is there a faster way to write to .csv file (or may be a text file with commas in it)? I am not required to form a table as shown above but I am doing so because I thought adding timestamp column and adding column names is easier. Please suggest if there is a faster way to do it because this code chokes if the array/table is really large.

Comment: Have you tried using the profiler to figure out what the bottleneck it? I believe the typical way of writing to files is to use `dlmwrite`, see e.g. https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/70018-how-to-write-cell-array-into-a-csv-file. Maybe that is faster?

Comment: hmm...I can check that out. Never used it.